# Serialized jsonb field doesn't work with filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have a class with a jsonb fiel,that is serialized.

```
class Solicitacao < ApplicationRecord
   serialize :dados
end
```

But when I try to filter into the json with this query doesn't work

```
Solicitacao.where('dados @> ?', {foo: '1234'}.to_json)
```

If I remove 'serialize :dados' the query works.
Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Just correcting "with a jsonb field"

Answer (score 0):

If a column is serialized it means that you're ignoring database abstractions with ruby code. In other words you cannot filter it using a database query but you can load and filter it using ruby

```
Collection.all.select{ |item| item.property == 123 }
```